# First submit button in HTML is redirecting to different URL

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

I am new to Thymeleaf and trying to Delete the first record but it is redirecting me to `http://localhost:8080/findall?_method=delete` . Although i am able to delete all the records and they are redirecting me to proper url `http://localhost:8080/delete/{id}`(except the fist one).

Whenever i am trying to delete the record by hitting the "http://localhost:8080/delete/{id}" from postman, i am able to do it. Thus, this has to do something with .html file.

Here is the code of display.jsp file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>Registration Table
</head>
<body>
<form>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Password</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
    <tr th:each="list : ${list}">
      <td th:text="${list.id}">ID</td>
      <td th:text="${list.userName}">Name</td>
      <td th:text="${list.userPassword}">Password</td>
      <!--  <td><a th:href="@{/delete/{id}}">Edit</a></td> -->

      <td>
        <form th:action="@{'/delete/{id}'(id=${list.id})}" th:method="delete">
          <input type="submit" value="Delete"/>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is controller.java

```
package com.spring.controller;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.request;

import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.xml.ws.Response;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView;

import com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpResponse;
import com.spring.model.Customer;
import com.spring.repository.CustomerRepo;

@RestController
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {

    @Autowired
    CustomerRepo rp;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/findall")
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView findall() {
    List<Customer> list = (List<Customer>) rp.findAll();
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.setViewName("display");
    mv.addObject("list", list);
    for (Customer element : list) {
        System.out.println("Element usernane: " + element.getUserName());
        System.out.println("Element password: " + element.getUserPassword());
    }
    mv.addObject("list", list);

    return mv;
}


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/display")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Customer> display() {
        return (List<Customer>) rp.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView home() {
        System.out.println("display home");
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("home");
        return mv;
    }


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value = "/delete/{id}")
    public ModelAndView deleteCourse(@PathVariable Long id) {
        System.out.println("deleting" + id);
        rp.delete(id);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:home");
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:home");
    }

}
```

[image]

If i click on delete button to delete the first record "Ravi" it will take me to URL "http://localhost:8080/findall?_method=delete" and wont delete the record(i want it to take me to url "http://localhost:8080/delete/1"). But if i click on any other button it is working fine and deleting the record.

I also checked the HTML code on browser. It is not generating same HTML code for each record.
It should be a very simple fix, Although i didnt find much content on Thymeleaf on stackoverflow.

Comment: If you suspect the html file, have a look at it in the browser - check what html file has been generated and what are the *actual* links generated there. (In your browser, got to "View source" - you will see the actual HTML file generated by Thymeleaf.)

Answer (score 2):

The `method` attribute accepts only [GET or POST](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp) as its value.

You can change `th:method` value to "post", and update your mapping in **Controller**:

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/delete/{id}")
```

**Update**
Also please remove the `<form>` enclosing your table.

Comment: Tried that, but it did not resloved the issue.

Comment: There are two other things that look suspicious to me, however I have no clue if they affect your page so much to result in such issue. First one is the `<form>` enclosing the whole table. What is this for? Forms shouldn't be nested. The second one is the iterator called the same as the `list` model attribute variable (inside `th:each`), however I couldn't find any piece of documentation to tell if this matters.

Answer (score 0):

I was using two forms in HTML. Removing the outer `<form>` tag from the HTML code resolved the issue.